# Dynamic bootstrap active tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, tabpanel

Is there a way I can get rid of the hard coded active tab and corresponding panel when outputting dynamic content? I would like somehow to make the first iteration of dynamic content to be the active tab + panel. The code below works fine, but the active tab/panel is pretty pointless in this scenario.

```
    <div role="tabpanel">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date"> 
    <li role="presentation"><a href="###DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#" aria-controls="#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#, #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'd')# #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'mmmm')#</a></li>     
    </cfoutput>    
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
    <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#">
    <cfoutput>#lesson_ID#<br></cfoutput>
    </div>
    </cfoutput>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `class="tab-pane<cfif lessons.currentRow eq 1> active</cfif>"` inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks John, so simple...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date"> 
      <li role="presentation" <cfif lessons.currentRow EQ 1>class="active"</cfif>>
        <a href="###DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#" 
           aria-controls="#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#" 
           role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
           >#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#, #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'd')# #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'mmmm')#
        </a>
      </li>     
    </cfoutput>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="#lessons.currentRow EQ 1 ? 'tab-pane active' : 'tab-pane'#" id="#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#">
        #lesson_ID#<br>
      </div>
    </cfoutput>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Note:-* You don't need to wrap `lesson_ID` with cfoutput as it is already inside a cfoutput unless you want to loop over the results returned from the outer `cfoutput`.

Comment: Thanks Beginner for detailed answer and extra pointer about cfoutput.

Comment: You _do_ need the extra `<cfoutput>` when you are nested inside an `cfoutput` that uses the `group` attribute. The inner `cfoutput` loops through records from the outer `cfoutput` group.